# query string params as array of objects - issues javascript

Tags: reactjs, parameters, grid, devexpress, query-string

I've got a problem!

I need to get in query string params encode something like this:

```
filters[0].columnName: createdBy
filters[0].value: ew
filters[0].operation: contains
filters[1].columnName: title
filters[1].value: eweqw
filters[1].operation: endsWith
```

but I just get nothing but...

```
filters: [name,"contains", o'}]
```

my code is:

```
  const getQueryStringFilters = (): string => {
    let filter = filters
      .reduce((acc, { columnName, value }) => {
        acc.push(encodeURIComponent(`[${columnName},"contains", ${value}'}]`));
        return acc;
      }, [])
      .join(',"and",');

    if (filters.length > 1) {
      filter = `[${filter}]`;
    }

    return filter;
  };
```

and I am using devexpress react-grid :( cannot find solution... somebody could help me out?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: current is filters=%5BcategoryName%2C%22contains%22%2C%20ew%27%7D%5D
But I need:
filters%5B0%5D.columnName=createdBy&filters%5B0%5D.value=ew&filters%5B0%5D.operation=contains&filters%5B1%5D.columnName=title&filters%5B1%5D.value=eweqw&filters%5B1%5D.operation=endsWith&page=0&size=20&lang=PL&types%5B0%5D=10